# Files in webpage are not loading in IE 10; But works fine in inprivate mode

Tags: webserver, internet-explorer-10

I have developed a website that has 6 audio files in it. It is perfectly working in Chrome, IE9, Firefox as well as iPad and android devices. But while loading in IE10, some of the audio files are not loading. There is no error message in console.

```
<audio id="audio1" preload="auto">
        <source src="foo.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'>
        <source src="foo.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'> 
</audio>
```

In the network tab in IE10, I checked the 'start capturing' and started browsing the pages containing the audios. Corresponding to the audio files, the status and MIME types were shown as 'pending' and the size was shown as 0 bytes. I checked the MIME type in the server and it was correctly set.

```
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

There were some peculiar things about the GET requests. Totally, there were three requests for the .mp3 file. The first request's result is shown as 'aborted'.

**Request Headers**

```
Accept    */*
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language    en-US
Connection    Keep-Alive
DNT    1
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG    1
Host    foobar.com
Pragma    getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Referer    http://foobar.com/
Request    GET /foobar/media/file1_001_01_01.mp3 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
```

The response header is empty.

The second GET requests' result is 206 partial content.

**Request Headers**

```
Request    GET /foobar/media/file1_001_01_01.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Accept    */*
If-Unmodified-Since    Mon, 17 Feb 2014 05:37:37 GMT
If-Match    "d12e3-b8a9-4f2938d9f8a40"
Range    bytes=24576-47272
User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
Referer    http://foobar.com/
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG    1
Pragma    getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language    en-US
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
Host    foobar.com
DNT    1
Connection    Keep-Alive
```

**Response Headers**

```
Response    HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content
Date    Tue, 18 Feb 2014 04:52:39 GMT
Server    Apache
Last-Modified    Mon, 17 Feb 2014 05:37:37 GMT
ETag    "d12e3-b8a9-4f2938d9f8a40"
Accept-Ranges    bytes
Content-Type    audio/mpeg
Content-Range    bytes 24576-47272/47273
Content-Length    22697
Age    2
X-Cache    HIT from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup    HIT from localhost:3128
Via    1.1 localhost:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7)
Connection    keep-alive
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
```

The third request's result is shown as "Pending".

**Request Header**

```
Request    GET /foobar/media/audio1_001_01_01.mp3 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
If-Modified-Since    Mon, 17 Feb 2014 05:37:37 GMT
If-None-Match    "d12e3-b8a9-4f2938d9f8a40"
Accept    */*
Referer    http://foobar.com/
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG    1
Pragma    getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language    en-US
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
Host    foobar.com
DNT    1
Connection    Keep-Alive
```

I loaded the my site in inPrivate Browsing in IE10 and it worked fine without any problem. Also, the problem occurs only when the site is loaded from server. I loaded the site from my localhoset in IE10 in normal mode and everything worked fine.

I have tried various things to make it work but nothing worked out yet. I have done the following things already:

- Cleared the cache and history by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Delete and 'Ok'.
- Done 'clear personal settings' in Advanced tab in Internet Options.
- Put my site into trusted sites.
- Disabled all plug-ins and add-ons.
- Disabled windows firewall.
- Disabled Antivirus Protection.
- Internet Options > Advanced > Accelerated graphics > checked 'Use software rendering
  instead of GPU rendering'.

I checked the site in IE10 in another computer and the problem persists in it too.

*Note: Originally this was posted in Super User, but i haven't got any response at all for three days. There is much greater possibility to get a response from stackoverflow. So please don't flag this post.*

Comment: We got the same issue.

Comment: For HTML5 the DOCTYPE must be correct - which one are you using? Have you captured and compared the html from localhost and from server?

Comment: Yes, they are same. I'm just pushing the data from localhost to server. So, both must be same.

Comment: Absolutely the same, also all the headers? And the DOCTYPE is what?

Comment: @harrymc <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1):

Using this [test page](http://textopia.org/androidsoundformats.html) I can hear mp3 just fine on IE10.
If it works for you too, try to find the difference by using a protocol sniffer.

Otherwise, try launching IE as administrator and listening for music.
If it then works, than reboot and try again as non-admin (normal account).
This method sometimes works to solve a permissions problem.

If nothing works, I suggest installing IE11 to (maybe) get out of this mess.

[EDIT]

Your first request shown in the post is nonsense, so was rightly aborted.

I have compared your other requests and responses to these in the above test page, and yours do not look logical or acceptable. Even your HTML `<audio>` tag is different.

I suggest to use a different media-files server in your website
than the one you are using now
and to improve your HTML code and especially the `<audio>` tag
to be more in line with that of test page.

Comment: I compared the request fields. There was only 1 difference. There were two additional fields: 'if-modified-since' and 'If-none-match' I have added the request details in the question.

Comment: Do you mean that the test page worked for you? If so, then the problem is in your computer. Try booting in Safe Mode with Network, to see if this is caused by some installed product, and if so use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check your startups. Else check all settings in IE including plugins.

Comment: I tried my site in three systems and this problem is present in all three.